# Changing Tomcat server name in response header, is that possible?

Tags: tomcat, configuration, response-headers, server-name

When a http request from a browser is made, typically the server container will send along in the header what server it was.

For tomcat it sends

```
   Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

I know I can overwrite this header, for each request, but there  is also the case for websockets and potentially other connections.

So, is there a way to change this at the tomcat configuration level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found this after posting the question:

Add this to server.xml in tomcat config folder.

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
                   connectionTimeout="20000"
                   redirectPort="8443"
                   server="MYSERVER"
                />
```

seems to work.

Restart server.

Comment: this on its own isnt very useful. post the name of the file where you add this & any other steps needed, e.g. restart

Answer (score 1):

Programmatically, given a `org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector`, it's:

`connector.setAttribute("server", "Something")`

Caution: Coyote ignores the server name if it's an empty string.

Comment: Note, that this won't apply for websockets header, which also has to make a similar call.

Answer (score 0):

GoTo your tomcat (server.xml) installation path 
exa:- C:/[Apache-Tomcat-Installation-Directory]/conf/server.xml

find:-
Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000"
enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443"

add:-
server="Any Server Name" 
inside the above tag. for safety purpose take a backup of xml file.