# Tomcat Response Header Server:"Server Name" Disappears with HTTPS

Tags: tomcat

My Server Name is configured like so in `server.xml`:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443"
               server="Fender Champ" />
...
<Connector
       protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
       port="8443" maxThreads="150"
       server="Fender Champ"
       scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
       keystoreFile="${user.home}/.keystore" keystorePass="[password]"
       clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS">
  <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
</Connector>
```

Which allows both 8080 and 8443 connections.

**I noticed that with HTTP, I can see my specified server name just fine:**
[image: HTTP Server: Response Header]

**However nothing seems to occur with HTTPS connections:**
[image: (Lack of) HTTPS Server: Response Header]

Does "server" exist as a possible attribute in HTTPS Tomcat? Should it be referred to as something else?

[Most](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36664816/changing-tomcat-server-name-in-response-header-is-that-possible) [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40845984/tomcat-response-header-fields) online is about HTTP, which works perfect, but HTTPS seems to completely ignore it. Is setting server name (or other response headers in general) possible for HTTPS connections? The [Tomcat Documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html) doesn't seem to detail anything other than `server` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html), Tomcat seems to only implement the `server` property on the standard protocol (HTTP), as defined in the section "**Standard Implementation**":

> The standard HTTP connectors (NIO, NIO2 and APR/native) all support the following attributes in addition to the common Connector attributes listed above.

The section detailing SSL/HTTPS does not mention `server` at all.